# Selecting Verbs: Want vs. Demand

Tags: verbs

I have two sentences that differ only by one word.

1. The sound of it drones. It’s like a stuck record. The ear **demands** some variety.
2. The sound of it drones. It's like a stuck record. The ear **wants** some variety

The first sentence sounds much more vivid to me. I can imagine a person demanding something. I see a man grabbing another by the collar, pinning him against the wall, and *demanding* money.

I can't see someone *wanting* something in that same way. It's just not as visual of a verb.

I'm trying to pull some sort of rule out of this example that will help me improve my writing, but i can't figure out what the rule would be.

Both of these are verbs, and both of them are action verbs. So if I were trying to explain it to someone, how would I phrase a principle that would help them pick a more vivid verb when writing a sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes understatement can be just the thing. If in every sentence you rush in at full charge, bands braying, cavalry in the van, with full artillery support, *demanding* some variety—well, now and then the ear may want a respite from all that, don't you think?

Comment: Agreed. I'm just trying to figure out how to categorize the verbs so that I can explain it to someone. Maybe the categorization is this: if you want to be more vivid, use a more specific verb? E.g. 'demand' is more specific than 'want'. 'Leap', is more specific than 'jump'. But maybe that's not the correct categorization. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Turn it around:  “If you want to be more dramatic choose a more vivid verb.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use metonymy (the “ear” representing the listener), you soften the reference slightly. To make a strong statement, you have to use a stronger verb.

The hungry people *called for food*, the empty bellies *cried for nourishment*.

It’s hard to give good examples, because using the whole expression (people) close to the part expression (belly) makes the example look like repetition for emphasis.

In English, the softer word is often a statement of volition. This sounds natural with a human or animal subject, but when a body part is used to stand in its place, volition does not seem as natural.

There is a well-known quote from Meister Eckhart: *Only the hand that erases can write the true thing.*  If you google this, however, you will find it often explained in terms of the writer being willing to modify their text. The hand, being inanimate, must *erase*. The human actor is assumed to be capable of nuance and judgement.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Those verbs (demand and leap) aren't necessarily more vivid, they're merely more extreme versions of the original verbs (want and jump). Perhaps your rule is find a more extreme version of the action you wish to describe? One that implies the actor has more intense feeling at the time of doing the action?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be looking for a way to find a simpatico verb for your subject. Your subject is the ear so perhaps think of the life of an ear.

The ear is a delicate organ and suffers assaults all its life.  It’s passive in effecting change outside of its own system but it does magnificent work internal to itself and the body it coexists with. The ear can’t act outside of itself.

An aggressive ear puzzles me. The mouth may demand justice for the ear but the ear can’t make demands unless it gets reprogrammed - and that is possible.

Using the same approach to demand vs want in your 2nd post: Demand is different than want - not more specific. Demands are made. Wants exist.